# Wagtail 1.10.1 elastic search issue

Tags: elasticsearch, wagtail

We upgraded Wagtail to 1.10.1, all went fine but we also had to increase the version of the elasticsearch python module, now the admin search only returns records that have been added since the upgrade.

I've tried python manage.py update_index but it says

Updating backend: default
Backend 'default' doesn't require rebuilding

Any ideas as to why old pages/images are no longer searchable?

Thanks

Joss

Comment: "default Backend 'default' doesn't require rebuilding" is the message I'd expect to see for the database backend, not the Elasticsearch one. Is it possible that your project is set up to use the database backend in the development settings, and Elasticsearch in production - in which case you'll need to specify production settings using something like `python manage.py update_index --settings=myproject.settings.production`?

Answer (score 1):

I need to run the update_index referencing a specific setting, it then worked. Though still not sure why the index had to be rebuilt after a Wagtail Upgrade?

Comment: I recommend to call the `update_index` command with required settings as part of your deploy process. Like `migrate` and other Django commands.